# Font limitation in MSAccess richtext edit tool

Tags: ms-access, richtextbox

Using MSAccess (2010+) richtext control. However, edit tool provides only limited number of font point sizes e.g. 6,8,10, 12; compared to editing within Word that provides e.g  8,9,10,11,12

This is driving my client mad as they wish to save text using 11pt - but this point size is not available.

Has anybody else observed this issue and is there a possible solution

Answer (score 4):

You can't select 11pt, because Access Richtext (actually HTML) doesn't store point sizes, but a fixed set of `<font size=1>` to `<font size=7>`.

You can inspect this by adding a textbox with the same control source, but with `TextFormat` = Plain text.

What you can do is to set the `FontSize` property of the rich text box to 11. Then all text **where no font size is specified**, will be shown at 11pt.

[image: Example]

It will even show `11` in the format toolbar for regular text.

Comment: Andre, thank you for your clear and concise answer to the question.