# Why is my MS Access text box (rich text) missing spaces between words?

Tags: ms-access

Sometimes, but not always, a word followed by a bold word in my MS Access text box will have the space between those words missing. The record containing this text DOES have the space its just when displayed in this text box it is missing.

Here is an image of the problem. The first line of the first paragraph between "berkenaan" and "tiga" is missing a space. The last line in the image also has the problem. Notice how other instances of bold do not have this problem.

[image: Spaces missing in rich text box]

- If I remove the ** PENTING... line, and the blank line, then add the missing space back in, then it renders correctly.
- I've examined the characters and there are no hidden characters in the string.
- I tried a regular space and a non-breaking space and the result is the same.
- If I put 2 spaces in then only one of them is missing and it ends up looking correct. This is not an ideal solution because sometimes this data is printed out to Word and I don't want 2 spaces there.

I can't see anything special about these 2 instances vs. the other correctly rendering instances in the same record.

EDIT: Here is the raw HTML.

```
<strong>**PENTING – SILA BACA DENGAN TELITI**</strong><br> <br>Sepanjang kaji selidik ini, kebanyakan soalan yang akan kami tanyakan adalah berkenaan <strong>tiga jenis produk yang berbeza</strong>. Justeru itu, untuk tujuan kaji selidik ini, sila rujuk rajah di bawah bagi membantu anda.<br> <br><strong>1.  Rokok biasa </strong>(rokok digulung sendiri dan buatan kilang) ialah rokok yang berisi <strong>tembakau</strong> dan perlu dinyalakan untuk pembakaran dan akan menghasilkan abu rokok.<strong>  </strong><br> <br><strong>2.  Produk vape </strong>(juga dikenali sebagai e-rokok) yang <strong>hanya memanaskan CECAIR (e-cecair) SAHAJA. </strong>Produk vape <strong>tidak</strong> mengandungi tembakau tetapi e-cecair kebiasaanya mengandungi nikotin dan berperisa.<br> <br>3. Produk yang terbaru dikenali sebagai <strong>produk tembakau dipanaskan </strong>(atau produk tembakau yang dipanaskan) tetapi tidak dibakar namun akan menghasilkan aerosol yang disedut. Produk tembakau yang dipanaskan ini kurang popular berbanding produk vape, dan kebiasaannya mengandungi tembakau berbentuk seperti rokok biasa.>
```

Comment: Please add the original HTML content of the text field. See here on how to see it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525535/3820271

Comment: This link didn't help with posting HTML but I managed to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Rich text boxes collapse some consecutive spaces into a single space. I think it is just how HTML is interpreted.

I replace all spaces with `&nbsp;` and that fixed the display issue. All spaces, including consecutive spaces appear as they should.